# How can I create 2 CSS images in this snippet without overlapping the text and links?

Tags: wordpress, css, background-image

I have a snippet in a WordPress widget produces it:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li><a title="Why Choose NetPrezence?" 
href="http://www.netprezence.net/choose-netprezence/">Why Choose NetPrezence?</a></li>

<li><a title="Meet the Founder of NetPrezence" href="http://www.netprezence.net/about-
me/">Meet the Founder</a></li>

<li><a title="Contact NetPrezence" href="http://www.netprezence.net/contact/">Contact 
NetPrezence</a></li>

<li><a title="Client Testimonials" href="http://www.netprezence.net/testimonials
/">Client Testimonials</a></li>

<li><a title="Porfolio" href="http://www.domain.com/portfolio
/">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>

<p><strong>NetPrezence LLC</strong><br />12870 Farmington 
Rd.<br />Livonia, MI 48150<br />888-888-8888<br />∴ mail@netprezence.net</p>
```

The current output looks like this:

[image: WordPress Widget]

What I'd like to do is to add my company logo in the top-left, above everything, **using CSS**, as opposed to inserting an image -- **without overlapping any text or links**.

Also, I'd like to add an e-mail icon to the left of the e-mail address in the lower-left, where there's a ∴ symbol. But I don't want to cover up the e-mail address, of course.

Any guidance in helping me achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TreeTree/qdX9Q/

You can use a `:before` on the `ul` to insert the logo. Unfortunately the email is just one `p` with no usable child elements so you may have to resort to some hardcoding like this:

```
ul:before {
    content:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/');
}

p {
    position:relative;
}

p:before {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/');
    background-size:15px 15px;
    content:'';
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, TreeTree, and thank you for the fiddle.  It looks like I'll have to fiddle around a little bit, perhaps with div tags, but I think you pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks again!